# Accessing content within raw files of a former SVN repository

Tags: svn, backup

I had a hard drive failure and was able to backup the raw files where SVN stored the repository (trunk/branches/etc folder).  I don't necessarily want to re-setup SVN as much as I'd just like to get/export content out of there.  Does anyone know what I would need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you have a backup of the raw files of the repository. Let's say it's in the folder `/tmp/svnrepo`. Just to make sure we're on the same page, a subversion repo has a directory layout like this:

```
svnrepo
├── README.txt
├── conf
├── db
├── format
├── hooks
└── locks
```

If you have this structure in your backup, then you can try if svn commands are working, for example list the files as a sanity check:

```
svn ls file:///tmp/svnrepo
```

If this works, then you can try to checkout, for example:

```
svn checkout file:///tmp/svnrepo/trunk
```

If the directory structure is damaged, or if these commands don't work, then I'm afraid there might be little hope. Disk recovery tools I used in the past were good at finding image, video and document files, and I have a feeling it will be difficult to recover Subversion's files.

If you don't mind losing the revision history, then it can be a better option to find an old checkout of the repository.

Comment: Sorry, I never got an email notification letting me know I got a response.

I get a message, svn: E155007 '<path to repos>' is not a working copy

Also, I look at the trunk folder in Explorer and it's empty, no hidden files as well.  I figured this was where it ultimately was supposed to be.  I was hoping there was some kind of a backup or cache that SVN uses, you know, when things get corrupted.

Comment: Yes unfortunately I think I might have nothing left...I do have an old checked out version, but I'm quite sure it wasn't the latest but it's the best I have...thanks

Comment: @VisionHive it seems you don't have `svn` installed, or it's not on your `PATH`.